# Python 3.6 importing own package fails (several solutions tried)

Tags: python, import, package

My project structure looks like this:

```
project
 |
 +---- __init__.py
 |
 +---- src
         |
         +---- start_script
         |
         +---- lib1

 |
 +---- run.sh
```

What I try to do is to run the script from the console (git bash) with (in *run.sh*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -r requirements.txt
python src/start_script.py
```

In *start_script.py*:

```
import src.lib1
```

And I get an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`.

I tried already using:

```
sys.path.append('../')
sys.path.append(os.path)
```

to add the files' paths and each directory has an *__init__.py* in there. Tried already nearly every sensible and senseless paths in the *run.sh* file for *PYTHONPATH*.
Does anyone have any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add:

```
src/__init__.py
```

so you define the module `src`.

Why not to use simply `import lib`?

The code `sys.path.append(os.path)` is wrong. `os.path` is a module, you cannot add a module as a path.